# Is Twitter still running on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I know Twitter initially ran on the Ruby on Rails platform.

Is this true today?

Answer (score 13):

Twitter has a very strange architecture.  They started out on Rails but now it's a **combination of Rails and Scala**.  They started replacing some of the backend functionality with Scala to get access to the JVM, but many of the pages are still served with Rails today.

Unfortunately Rails has gotten a bit of a reputation for not being scalable enough due to Twitter moving away from it.  This is (in my opinion) a bad misconception - the problem Twitter was having was with long-running processes and with green threads (which don't use the OS threads).  Also, how many applications have 300 million+ users?

Comment: More specifically, the Message Queueing server was moved to Scala.

Comment: +1 for this "Also, how many applications have 300 million+ users?"

Answer (score 1):

1 )twitter forms use

*CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery): like rails

2 )twitter is a REST application   : like rails

'They started out on Rails but now it's a combination of Rails and Scala'  and a big chunk of javascript

It 's  (thin MVC + big javascript )  concept ,like gmail

Comment: You make Twitter sound like a malicious application when you say CSRF.

Comment: no, rails use an  Cross Site Request Forgery PROTECTION  ,a token in every form.

Comment: I fail to see how CSRF is a concept limited to Rails?

Comment: Jaco Pretorius, it is not. but it comes by default with Rails. Forms automatically generates hash to prevent CSRF